# Can/should I use Firebase with Ionic 2 or Xamarin?

Tags: xamarin, ionic-framework, firebase, ionic2

Having just seen [this blog post](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/05/firebase-expands-to-become-unified-app-platform.html) detailing the major enhancements that have been made to Firebase, I'm keen to try out some of its features, particularly messaging, auth and real time database.

It has documentation for native Android and iOS, but for various reasons I would rather work with a hybrid platform.

Is it feasable to use Firebase with [Ionic 2](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/) or [Xamarin](https://www.xamarin.com/) at this stage or would I be better off seeking alternative solutions to implement these features?

There doesn't seem to be a C# API for Xamarin, and I'm not sure if the "web" API would fit into an Ionic 2 app (with Angular 2).

Comment: Keep in mind, if you feel like doing some work, you can bind the Java Android and Objective-C/Swift iOS libraries for use in a Xamarin app. I've done this for a few relatively small libraries, and it isn't too bad. But with a large library, it might not be worth the effort.

Comment: The [angularfire2](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2) project is a way to go if you choose working with Ionic. They are currently upgrading to work with the FirebaseSDKv3 and you can follow/contribute with the project. It would be my choice because angular+firebase is a huge combination, both in time saving and code style.

Comment: Bindings are being created as we speak for Xamarin.

Comment: I'm interested in this question to use firebase in combination with Xamarin. Any suggestions?

Comment: @JonDouglas any news on that? I see Android pre-release packages but nothing for iOS

Comment: @AlexSorokoletov Not yet. It will land in https://github.com/xamarin/GoogleApisForiOSComponents when it's complete. Otherwise there is a REST client that you could use: https://github.com/ziyasal/FireSharp